# Mysql select fields from tbl where from_date is not null and to_date is null or not

Tags: mysql

I have a script as below:

```
while from_date is not null do
     if to_date is null then
          select * from product where now >= from_date; (1)
     else
          select * from product where from_date <= now <= to_date (2)
end while;
```

It means that, I need select product if from_date is not null and to_date is null or not. If null then case (1), else not null then case(2). Both case (1) and case (2), product will be added to select. I want to convert it to mysql query, please help me!

Demo table:

```
   id  |    from_date              |      to_date               |   item   |   price   |
    1      2014-03-14                   2014-06-26                   25         75
    2      2014-03-27                     NULL                       25         50
    3      2014-03-27                   2014-06-01                   26         80 
    4      2014-04-02                     NULL                       26         100 
    5          NULL                       NULL                       26         200
```

I want to select rows with id from 1 to 4, this is result I want :)

Comment: Since you never change `from_date` nor `to_date`; that code will either do nothing or go into an infinite loop (and return nothing). Please show us some sample data, and what you want returned.

Comment: I think the OP meant that the from_date is a column in the table itself. So this would work : select * from product where from_date is not null and to_date is null and now >=from_date
union all
select * from product where from_date is not null and to_date is not null and now >= from_date and now <= to_date

Comment: I want to create new product list. New product list is set when atleast exsist from_date, if to_date is null then product is new forever :)

Comment: I updated my demo table and result I want.

Comment: Did my suggestion work for you?

Comment: I tried to draw a diagram and I saw the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from product 
where from_date is not null 
and to_date is null 
and now >=from_date

union all 

select * from product 
where from_date is not null 
and to_date is not null 
and now >= from_date 
and now <= to_date
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I have an other query work perfectly: $sql = 'SELECT id, name, price, image FROM product WHERE (from_date IS NOT NULL AND to_date IS NOT NULL AND CURDATE() BETWEEN from_date AND to_date) OR (from_date IS NOT NULL AND ISNULL(to_date) AND CURDATE() >= from_date)';